# AttributeError: 'element_to_be_clickable' object has no attribute 'click' python3.7

Tags: selenium, python-3.7, attributeerror

As my code shows, I am trying to automate the process of logging and other things using selenium in python 3.7. I am struck as it is showing "AttributeError: element_to_be_clickable has no object click" in the line botton_to_click().

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

base = 'https://www.wsj.com'
url = 'https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=cybersecurity&min-date=2018/04/01&max-date=2019/03/31&isAdvanced=true&daysback=90d&andor=AND&sort=date-desc&source=wsjarticle,wsjpro&page=1'

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_id('editions-select').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('na,us').click()
botton_to_click = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable, ((By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Sign In')]")))
botton_to_click.click()
browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('@#$%*&^%@#$')
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('@#*$%^!#')
browser.find_element_by_id('basic-login').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('masthead-container').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('searchInput').send_keys('cybersecurity')
browser.find_element_by_name('ADVANCED SEARCH').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('dp1560924131783').send_keys('2018/04/01')
browser.find_element_by_id('dp1560924131784').send_keys('2019/03/31')
browser.find_element_by_id('wsjblogs').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('wsjvideo').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('interactivemedia').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('sitesearch').click()

browser.close()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma after element_to_be_clickable as given below, It may resolve your issue.

```
botton_to_click = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable, ((By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Sign In')]")))
```

to

```
botton_to_click = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Sign In')]")))
```

Comment: In a way, it solved the question I asked. But It is showing a different error. TimeOut. So I think the problem is in XPath. Thanks for the help. I will raise another question for my current problem. I have upvoted the answer.